# looking for a way to search through an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to add an item in the array and then search for it by just the name. 
i have it working but in order for it to work I have to put name - quantity im not sure how I can extract just the name from cargohold[i] and then see if matches to the input from the user

this is how im adding the information to the array

```
    private void addItem(String cargohold[]) {
        // TODO: Add an item that is specified by the user

        cargoItem itemAdded = new cargoItem();   
        System.out.println("What Inventory locker would you like to add an item to?");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        userInput = userInput - 1;
        System.out.println("Name of Item: ");
        input.nextLine();
         itemAdded.name= input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Quantity: ");
        itemAdded.quantity = input.nextInt();
        cargohold[userInput] = itemAdded.name + " - " + itemAdded.quantity;
    }

private void searchItems(String cargohold[]) {
        // TODO: Search for a user specified item
        System.out.println("What Item are you looking for?");
        System.out.println("This input is case sensitive");
        String searchInput = input.nextLine();
        for (int i =0; i<cargohold.length; i++){
            cargoItem itemAdded = new cargoItem();

            y = cargohold[i];
              if(searchInput.equals(itemAdded.name)){
                System.out.println("Found Item "+ searchInput+ "in locker"+ i);
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Not Found");
            }     
        }
class cargoItem {
    String name;
   int quantity;
}
```

Comment: In java, classes normally start with an upper case letter (CargoItem), which methods and variables start with a lower case letter (cargoHold[]).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `cargoItem[]` array instead of `String[]` array, that way you can extract the name by simply calling `cargohold[i].name`.

If you are set on using `String[]` array and you are using the format `name - quantity` then you can extract the name by calling `String theName = cargohold[i].split(' - ')[0];` and `String theQuantity = cargohold[i].split(' - ')[1];` To split the String between " - " and extract the name and quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You have `cargohold[userInput] = itemAdded.name + " - " + itemAdded.quantity;`

Means you have `name` and `quantity` as a string.

To search for a name, you have to use the below.

```
private void searchItems(String cargohold[]) {
        // TODO: Search for a user specified item
        System.out.println("What Item are you looking for?");
        System.out.println("This input is case sensitive");
        String searchInput = input.nextLine();
        for (int i =0; i<cargohold.length; i++){
            String y = cargohold[i];
            String name - itemAdded.split("-")[0];

              if(searchInput.equals(name)){
                System.out.println("Found Item "+ searchInput+ "in locker"+ i);
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Not Found");
            }     
        }
```

1. I removed unused new object in the search method
2. Initialized `y`
3. Taken name by splitting

There are problems the way of storing:

1. What if data contains `-`
2. You should use `cargoItem` class with overloaded `equals, hashcode` method for better solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the class `CargoItem`. And use `List<CargoItem>` to store data.

Your class be like

```
class cargoItem {
   String name;
   int quantity;
   int locker;
}
```

Add you data in map

```
private void addItem(List<CargoItem> list){
      ...
      itemAdded.locker = userinput
      list.add(itemAdded);
      ...
}
```

Search your data from list

```
private void searchItems(List<CargoItem> list) {
     ...
     for(CargoItem item : list){
         if(searchInput.equals(item.name)){
            System.out.println("Found Item "+ searchInput+ "in locker"+ item.locker);
        }
     }
     ...
}
```